# Input File Maximum Size

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new at Laravel. How can I limit the size of input file to 5mb?

This is my controller :

```
public function add_project_activity(Request $request){
    $id_rotation        = $request->id_rotation;
    $input_activity     = $request->activity_name;
    $input_detail       = $request->detail_activity;
    $input_file         = $request->file;

    $nik = Sentinel::getUser()->nik;

    if (!empty($request->file) && $request->hasFile('file')) {
        $new_id         = self::check_id();

        $filename       = $input_file->getClientOriginalName();
        $new_filename   = "evidence_" . $new_id . "-" . $filename;
        $upload_file    = $input_file->storeAs('public/accelerate/'.$nik.'/',$new_filename);

        $submit_data = AccelerateProjectActivity::create([
            'status'            => 'draft',
            'activity_name'     => $input_activity,
            'detail_activity'   => $input_detail,
            'evidence'          => $new_filename,
            'month'             => $request->month,
            'id_rotation'       => $id_rotation,
        ]);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'your message,here');
    } elseif(empty($request->file)){
        $submit_data = AccelerateProjectActivity::create([
            'status'            => 'draft',
            'activity_name'     => $input_activity,
            'detail_activity'   => $input_detail,
            'month'             => $request->month,
            'id_rotation'       => $id_rotation,
        ]);
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

This is my view of input :

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label>Evidence Activity</label>
                    <input type="file" name="file" class="form form-control" accept="application/msword, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/pdf">
                </div>
```

Thank you, I'm confused at this, how to place the validator in my controller.
Hope you're answer my question. Greetings.

Comment: Hi buddy, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Comment: Another ways maybe, it's work but I won't use that

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the `upload_max_size` on the fly in the `add_project_activity()` controller method.

```
public function add_project_activity(Request $request) {
    @ini_set('upload_max_size' , '5M');
    ...
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

OR edit php.ini file

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 5M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 5M
```

OR edit your .htaccess file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 5M
php_value post_max_size 5M
```

But these last 2 options will be global, for all your file upload situations.

Comment: Where should I place the code?

Comment: Can you combine my code with your code? I'm still confused

Comment: Doesn't work, still can upload more than 5mb size

Comment: If it doesn't work you'll have to edit your php.ini file or .htaccess file in the webroot. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more simple setup . You can edit it in htaccess. Or you can set upload limit in php.ini file. Depending on which system you are working you can have different setting. But you should take a look at the configurations.